# How can I change this one line for loop to normal for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

My question how can i convert the following one line for loop in this function to normal for loop.

```
def get_batches(dataset, t=1):
   data_order = DataFrame(dataset)  
   h = [data_order.shift(index) for index in range(1, t + 1)]
   h.append(data_order)
   data_order = concat(h, axis=1)                         
   return data_order
```

When i follow the same, it doesn't work!

So far I've tried this:

```
def get_batches(dataset, t=1):
    data_order = DataFrame(dataset) 
    h=[]
    for index in range(1, t + 1):
         h.append(data_order.shift(index))
    data_order = concat(h, axis=1)
    return data_order
```

But I wasn't sure if this was right because I was getting an error.

Edit:
Another example:

```
[variable for variable in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, variable))]
```

It is converted as:

````
variable = []
for i in listdir(path):
     if isfile(join(path, variable)):
         variable.append(i)```
````

Comment: What's the problem with one line for? It looks neat and follows the "python way".

Comment: I am learning python and i want to compare the both results and for practice purpose.

Comment: Try adding ```h.append(data_order)``` after the for loop, this might be the problem.

Comment: i didn't get it.. outside the for loop ? or after h.append(data_order.shift(index)) should i add this line?

Comment: just like in the answer below

Comment: Unfortunalty, it doesn't work.

Comment: It's a list comprehension, not a "one-line for loop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the `h.append(data_order)` from the previous code.

The code should have been like this:

```
def get_batches(dataset, t=1):
   data_order = DataFrame(dataset)
    h=[]  
   for index in range(1, t + 1)]:
       h.append(data_order.shift(index))
   h.append(data_order)
   data_order = concat(h, axis=1)                         
   return data_order
```